# Как убрать пробелы между строками?

Tags: sql-server

Ребят, как убрать пробелы между строками средствами T-SQL?

```html
<span class="p-title">Вес </span><span class="p-value"> 140</li>          <li><span>Area di stampa </span>65</li>          <li><span>Misura</span> 50</li>
```

Comment: Укажите версию сервера. Ну или сразу смотрите  в сторону CLR и регулярных выражений.

Comment: надо полагать, что число пробелов произвольное?

Answer (score 0):

Данный код убирает множественные пробелы:

```
declare @string AS varchar(4000)
SET @string = '<span class="p-title">Вес </span><span class="p-value"> 140</li>          <li><span>Area di stampa </span>65</li>          <li><span>Misura</span> 50</li>'
SELECT @string
 SELECT REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    LTRIM(RTRIM((@string)))
                ,'  ',' '+CHAR(7) )  
            ,CHAR(7)+' ','')        
        ,CHAR(7),'') AS ClearedString
```

подробнее об алгоритме работы можно прочитать в  [данной статье](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/)

**Важно:** решение будет убирать множественные пробелы и не повреждать данные строки при условии, что символ  - он же `char(7)`, не будет встречаться в строке с данными. Если он может присутствовать в строке - вам необходимо выбрать гарантированно неиспользуемый и заменить в коде все вхождения `char(7)` на новый символ.